# How do I change camera targets when following a path?

Tags: camera, path

I have a nurbs path setup and my camera operates following the path. I can get it to track an empty, but I want it to change between a couple of empties as it progresses down the path.

Is there a way to do this using the timeline?

Comment: Don't think it can be done in Timeline, only Camera can be activated in a way like this. But you can add as many Tracking constraints as Empties you got, and then animate Influence value to switch between them. For first empty it will be 1 to 0 value and 0 to 1 for second.

Comment: I see what you mean, thats close. But how would I change the influence as it moves down the path? Key frames? Sorry I am very new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "change" camera targets, but you can have several *Track-To* constraints in the same object with different influence values at any given time.

Just keyframe the *Influence* parameter over the course of the animation so it points where you want at the correct moment.

[image]